# system locks up starting today when I start Firefox -- ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox

I would like ideas as to why Firefox is locking up my 20.04 Ubuntu so I can fix it.
I did the usual, started the computer, started my NordVPN and then opened up Firefox. I have done this since I installed 20.04 without problems. But Firefox now locks up my computer.   The first time it was when I hit a  link to another page, it locked up, but I was able to right click on the Firefox icon and "quit".   But when I restarted the computer and tried it again, now it just locks up and right clicking the icon does nothing.   The power down menu on the upper right does not work either.   I have to hit the power off button on the computer.  I did an update on the software for ubuntu 20.04 thinking maybe I was missing something, but it still locked up.
I thought I should maybe uninstall it and then install it again.  On Ubuntu 18.04, if you right click on the icon you can 'show details' and install or uninstall, but on version 20.04 there is no 'details' in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it.  I started system and not firefox.   Then went into the applications and uninstalled firefox and then re-installed it.  It seems to work fine now.

---

One question that came up. .. if you go into the applications and search for firefox there are TWO.   There is a "firefox" and a "firefox web browser".   Anyone know the difference??

---